# How to get a codebehind variable into the Text property of a CheckboxField

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, ascx

What I'm trying to do is like

```
<asp:CheckBoxField DataField="MyValue" HeaderText="My Value" text="<%= MyProperty %>"/>
```

where

```
public string MyProperty;
```

is in the codebehind file.

However this just renders `"<%= MyProperty %>"` is a string.

Any idea how to do this (without JavaScript)?

Comment: Are you using Gridview with checkbox inside in a row?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with a gridview control do it like this:
html:

```
<asp:CheckBoxField DataField="MyValue" ID="chkfield" HeaderText="My Value"/>
```

Code Behind:

```
CheckBoxField cf = new CheckBoxField();
cf = (DGGeneric.HeaderRow.FindControl("chkfield") as CheckBoxField);
cf.Text = "This is your property text";
```

Comment: I get error "ID is not a valid attribute of CheckBoxField" in my ascx